# Игнорировать все файлы кроме тех, что имеют определённые расширения

Tags: git, gitignore

У меня есть файл `.gitignore` следующего содержания:

```
*
!/.gitignore
!CMakeLists.txt
!*.cpp
!*.hpp
```

Согласно задумке он должен разрешать добавление:

- самого `.gitignore` в корне репозитория,
- файлов `CMakeLists.txt` в любых папках и подпапках,
- файлов формата `.cpp` и `.hpp` в любых папках и подпапках,

а всё остальное запрещать.

Однако разрешающие правила действуют только на файлы, расположенные в корне репозитория. И это, в принципе, [логично](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> ***ФОРМАТ ПРАВИЛ***
>
> - *Необязательный префикс «!», инвертирующий действие правила; любой подпадающий по него файл, исключённый правилами выше, будет включён обратно. **Невозможно включить файл, если он находится в уже исключённой папке.** Git не просматривает содержимое исключённых папок в целях оптимизации, а потому правила не распространяются на их содержимое.*
>
> ---
>
> ***PATTERN FORMAT***
>
> - *An optional prefix “!” which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.** Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.*

То есть первое правило, исключающее все подпапки, практически аннулирует действие разрешающих правил ниже.

**Вопрос:** как надо правильно включать только файлы с определёнными расширениями вне зависимости от их расположения и уровня вложенности?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
*
!*/
!.gitignore
!.gitattributes
!.gitmodules
!CMakeLists.txt
!*.cpp
!*.hpp
```

Добавил ещё пару часто встречающихся файлов конфигурации git.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего необходимо задвать правило указывая ** директорию.

Например

```
!**/*.hpp
!**/*.cpp
```

Comment: поскольку `*` игнорирует в том числе директории, в них не будет осуществляться поиск, так что `**/*.cpp` ничего не найдет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin таки да, приходится взаимоисключения писать