# Настройка .gitignore в SourceTree

Tags: git, gitignore, source-tree

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить игнорирование файлов в программе SourceTree.
К примеру в репозиторий входит проект Delphi. Нужно отслеживать только файлы с расширением pas, dfm, res, dpr.

Пишу в файле .gitignore:

```
/*/
/*
!/*.pas
!/*.dfm
!/*.res
!/*.dpr
```

Но никаких изменений. Отслеживаются все файлы.

Comment: Правильный файл .gitignore тут: [Игнорировать все файлы кроме тех, что имеют определённые расширения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681952). Если он не срабатывает и игнорируются все файлы, то и причина решение описаны здесь: [Не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432432/)

Comment: Кстати, очень рекомендую выкинуть SourceTree и пользоваться консолью. Там есть всё что нужно и оно всегда работает.